# Changing Cookie Domains

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, dns, session-cookies

I use apache as a proxy to my application web server and would like to on the fly, change the domain name associated with a sessionid cookie.

The cookie has a .company.com domain associated with it, and I would like using apache mod rewrite (or some similar module), transparently change the domain to app.company.com. Is this possible ? and if so, how would one go about it ?

Comment: Change it at what point exactly? For the server or for the client? I don't understand.

Comment: Change it at the server. Basically, since apache is configured as a proxy server, all traffic between the client and the app server gets routed through the apache server. And what I am trying to accomplish is to change the cookie domain that is set by the app, in the apache proxy before the cookie reaches the client.

Comment: @user I see. I think this is the kind of thing big fat reverse proxies can do - no idea whether Apache is capable of that. I'm still not sure I understand why you need this, though. Won't an outgoing request set the cookie for the proxy domain in the first place?

Comment: `app.company.example` is an invalid *domain* value. It either needs to be `.app.company.example` or just omit it so that the current domain is used.

Answer (score 4):

You can only change the domain of a cookie **on the client, or when it's being set on the server**. Once a cookie has been set, the path and domain information for it only exists on the client. So existing cookies can't have their domain changed on the server, because that information isn't sent from the client to the server.

For example, if you have a cookie that looks like this on your local machine:

```
MYCOOKIE:123, domain:www.test.com, path:/
```

Your server will only receive:

```
MYCOOKIE:123
```

on the server. Why isn't the path and domain sent? Because the browser keeps that information on the client, and doesnt bother sending it along, since it only sends this cookie to your server *if* the page is at ***www.test.com*** and at the path ***/***.

Since it's your server, you should be able to change your code that creates new cookies. If you felt you needed to do it outside of your code for some reason, you could do so with something like the following, but you'd have to look exactly at how your cookie is being written in the header to match it exactly. The following is an untested guess at a workable solution for this, using Apache's `mod_headers`:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header edit Set-Cookie (.*)(domain=.company.com;)(.*) $1 domain=app.company.com; $2
</IfModule>
```

You can also use `mod_headers` to change the cookie received from the client, like so, if need be:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  RequestHeader edit Cookie "OLD_COOKIE=([0-9a-zA-Z\-]*);" "NEW_COOKIE_NAME=$1;"
</IfModule>
```

This would only rename cookies you receive in the request.

Comment: Should that not be

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header edit Set-Cookie (.*)(domain=.company.com;)(.*) $1 domain=app.company.com; $3
</IfModule>

as you are capturing 3 patterns in your regex and replacing $2 (domain)

Comment: Good point - I don't have this setup anywhere to test, so maybe? But I did have this working at one point, and copied in what I had from then at that time. so maybe both would work?

Comment: This does not work for me in Apache at all. `mod_headers` works but cannot edit the `Set-Cookie` header.

Comment: Most of your answer is a response to a misunderstanding of the original question, and the one useful bit about "Header edit Set-Cookie" doesn't seem to work.  The original poster is pretty clearly looking for something like ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain.  (which might not have existed in 2011)

Comment: @dataless - all I know is this worked for me back in 2015... It may not be the best approach, but it worked. I took a look and it sounds like `ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain` would work good to me! I don't do tons of Apache work, but cobbled the above together when trying to figure out how to do this for our own use case, and didnt see `ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain`, which sounds great.

Answer (score 4):

```
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain company.com app.company.com
```

or interchanging domains (as you are not clearly defining which is internal/external).

ref: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_proxy.html#ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know any module that provides such feature. So I guess you will need to write your own [output filter](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/filter.html) using [mod_ext_filter](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ext_filter.html) that does this for you.

But if you have control over the other server, it might suffice to just omit the cookie’s *domain* value so that the client will automatically choose the requested domain as the cookie’s domain.

Comment: I ended up just creating an intermediate page that via javascript changed the cookie domain to the proxy server (by omitting the domain value) and then re-directed user to the target page. That seemed to resolve the issue. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just creating an intermediate page that via javascript changed the cookie domain to the proxy server (by omitting the domain value) and then re-directed user to the target page. That seemed to resolve the issue. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

If your web-app is capturing the `Host:` header and using that to determine the `domain=` portion of the cookie, you might also consider the Apache directive

`ProxyPreserveHost On`

which relays the `Host:` header from the client.

This only works if your app is designed to assume that its domain name is whatever the client suggests with the Host header.  If your app is one of these, this will not only fix your cookies, but also any absolute URLs that the application generates, which can save you the overhead of otherwise needing to [enable mod_substitute](https://serverfault.com/questions/684359/is-it-possible-to-replace-content-on-every-page-passed-through-a-proxy-similar-t)

Answer (score 0):

```
ProxyPass         "/" "http://company.com/"
ProxyPassReverse  "/" "http://company.com/"
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain "company.com" "app.company.com"
```

**Note:** If it comes second in ProxyPass it should be first in ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain... I spent half a day or more figuring this out :-/

Also see: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreversecookiedomain