# Tomcat: how to set an XML attribute in context.xml as null?

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, xerces, xerces2-j

I would like to dynamically configure `sessionCookieDomain` as an environment variable. In my `context.xml`, I have:

```
<Context sessionCookieDomain="${environment.sessionCookieDomain}">
...
</Context>
```

given that the `environment.sessionCookieDomain` is a configuration property.

I would like to only set it in certain conditions, otherwise, leave it to default (which is `null`). Is that possible?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `sessionCookieDomain="${environment.sessionCookieDomain}"` - E.g. tomcat doesnt barf on startup?  And obviously you cant just do `<Context/>` or remove the element  as there's other "stuff" in there correct?

Comment: @JGlass To answer the first question: if I remove `sessionCookieDomain="${environment.sessionCookieDomain}"`, how would I be able to configure the `sessionCookieDomain` setting in certain environment? For 2nd question, yes there are other stuff there.

Comment: Well, with other stuff there - guess that's a bad idea ;-)  If "sessionCookieDomain" is indeed a System.Property once your app is running - can't you just programmatically set it to null during some conditions and set to another domain under other conditions?

Comment: Maybe something like [How to safely change the session cookie domain or name in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32763252/how-to-safely-change-the-session-cookie-domain-or-name-in-production) though it uses an apache library - also interesting [How to properly set jsessionid cookie path behind reverse proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486498/how-to-properly-set-jsessionid-cookie-path-behind-reverse-proxy) that is if you can use Servlet Spec 3